# Number of congruence relations of a 4-element non-cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, congruences, normal-subgroups

How many congruence relations does a 4-element non-cyclic group have?

Am I right that I have to find the normal subgroups in order to find the congruence relations?

Thanks

Comment: The congruence relations on a group are in bijection with the normal subgroups. Do you know what the correspondence between them is? Thus, counting one is equivalent to counting the other. Can you determine the number in this case?

Comment: I know the correspondence between them, but how to identify the normal subgroups, thanks. @anon

Comment: Do you know what the group is, first of all?

Comment: Yes and also that the properties of the normal subgroups. for every element _x_ $\in$ **_N_** (normal subgroup) and every element _a_ in **_G_**, it holds that _axa*_ $\in$ **_N_**. Also _x_ $\equiv$ _y_ iff _xy*_ $\in$ **_N_**. One element is the neutral element, denoted by **_e_**, but what can I say about the rest? @anon

Comment: You say you know what the group is - well, show us you know. What is the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4-element non-cyclic group is Klein four-group. An example of this group is the group $\mathcal{P}(S)$ where $S = \{a,b\}$ with the symmetric difference as the binary operation.

There are five congruences on this group by counting the normal subgroups which two of them are trivial normal subgroups. The three non-trivial ones are $\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$, $\{\varnothing,\{b\}\}$ and $\{\varnothing,\{a,b\}\}$